# continuity of $e^{-1/z}$ in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity, exponential-function, uniform-continuity

Let f be the function defined by $f(z)=e^{-1/z}$ in $\mathbb C$, prove that $f$ is continuous in the set $0< \vert z \vert < 1$ and $\vert arg(z) \vert <\pi/2$ but it's not uniformly continuous on it.

I think an easy way to prove it is firstly to show that $f$ is analytic, therefore f is differentiable. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Is there an easier way to prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For continuity, note that $-1/z$ maps $\{0<|z|<1\}$ into $\{1<|z|<\infty\}$ continuously, $e^z$ is continuous everywhere, and the composition of continuous maps is continuous. As for uniform continuity, consider the behavior of $f(x+i\sqrt x) - f(x)$ as $x\to 0^+.$

Comment: So should I use the definition $ \epsilon$-$ \delta$ and the function f(x+i$\ sqrt{x}$)-f(x) to show that f is uniformly continuous?

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say x tends to 0+, I mean how to use it to proof continuity

Comment: The idea is that $|x+i\sqrt x -x|\to 0,$ but $f(x+i\sqrt x) - f(x)$ doesn't. That shows $f$ is not uniformly continuous in this region.

Comment: I see intuitively that -1/z maps {0<lzl<1} into {1<lzl<$ \infty$} continuously but my exercise says "prove it" so how can I prove it formally?

Comment: Or I just write: Note that... (like you wrote)

Comment: @AaronMartinez Take $z=re^{it}$ and see what happens.

Comment: is it just a point (the origin)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Pick any $z \neq 0.$ Then let $B$ be a ball of radius $r = |z|/2$. Restricted to just on that ball, the function $g(z)=-1/z$ is continuous. Also exp is continuous everywhere. Thus $f=exp(g)$ is the composite of continuous functions.

Comment: when you pick z$ \neq$0 it's because we want continuity in 0<lzl<1 ,i.e. strictly bigger than 0 right?

Comment: I think the ball B must have another conditions, like open and bounded by 1. Am I correct?

Comment: @AaronMartinez I'm not the person that posted the answer, but you are right that if $z \neq 0$, then $|z| > 0$.  (It's actually true that $z \neq 0 \iff |z| = 0$.)  Also, by definition of a ball, balls are always open.  But you're right that for this answer to work out, we have to choose the ball a little more carefully.  You originally wanted to show the function is continuous on $z$ satisfying $0<|z|<1$, i.e., for $z$ in $B(0,1) - \{0\}$, where $B(0,1)$ is the ball around $0$ of radius $1$...

Comment: @AaronMartinez ...So, you want to show the function is continuous at each $z$ in $B(0,1) - \{0\}$.  Well, then let $z$ be an element in $B(0,1) - \{0\}$.  Since $B(0,1) - \{0\}$ is open, by definition of open we can find some $\epsilon > 0$ so that $B(z,\epsilon) \subseteq (B(0,1) - \{0\})$.  In this ball, we clearly have $|z'| > 0$ for each $z' \in B(z, \epsilon)$.  But then $-\frac{1}{z}$ is continuous on this ball by the original answer, and so is $e^{z}$, and composing continuous functions gives a continuous function, so $e^{-\frac{1}{z}}$ is continuous on $B(z,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @AaronMartinez That means $e^{-\frac{1}{z}}$ is continuous at the $z \in B(0,1) - \{0\}$ that we fixed earlier.  But this $z$ was an arbitrary element of $B(0,1) - \{0\}$.  Thus, the function is continuous on $B(0,1) - \{0\}$.  **Note:** I'm not necessarily endorsing this method of proof or saying this is the right way.  I'm just trying to fill in the details I think are missing from the original answer based on the good questions you had.  There may b\e a better or nicer way to prove this.  The issue I have with this answer is you'd have to verify $-\frac{1}{z}$ and $e^z$ are continuous first

Comment: oh wow I got it, thank you @user46944 you definitely brightened up my mind :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57726/discussion-between-aaron-martinez-and-user46944).

Comment: @AaronMartinez Sorry for not responding.  It was late at night when I commented and I went to sleep after posting.

Comment: @user46944 oh ok no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As $f(z)=-\frac{1}{z}$ is analytic in $0<\vert z\vert<1$ then so is $e^{-\frac{1}{z}}$.